# How to get a variable from a php file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What I'm trying to do is query a variable in my check.php file and pull that variable to my index.php file, compare it to a different variable, and reload the page if they don't match. 
This is what I have so far:

check.php:

```
some query
echo json_encode($checknew);
```

index.php:

```
var checkold = "<?php echo $old['ertek'];?>"; 

function checkupdates() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check.php',
        dataType: 'json'});

        if (checkold != checknew){
            location.reload(); 
       }  
    , 3000)}
};

$( document ).ready( checkupdates );
```

How do I "catch" the $checknew variable from php and turn it into a variable for my function?

Comment: You are not using the `ajax` call correctly. Need to use `.done(function() {}` to get the echo value from check.php

Comment: success: function() { and here you can do whatever you want with your variables that you got from backend }

Comment: Also, `var checkold = "<?php echo $old['ertek'];?>"; ` is not doing what you think it is. `checkold` will contain the literal string `<?php echo $old['ertek'];?>` not the value inside `$old['ertek']`. Please check out [Ajax Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Any suggestion how should I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `check.php` you are echoing `json_encode($checknew)`. Be specific what you are writing if it is only one value then you can simply write `echo $checknew;`.
And your JAVASCRIPT should be like this

```
var checkold = "<?php echo $old['ertek'];?>"; 

function checkupdates() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check.php', 
        success:function(checknew){
          if (checkold != checknew){
            location.reload(); 
          }  
        }
    });

     },3000);
}

$( document ).ready( checkupdates() );
```

Comment: yea, checknew is only one value, not an array

Comment: write only `echo $checknew;` :)

Comment: ok so I did what milan suggested and is working now, the only problem is the page reloads every time, even if I set $checkold="1" and var checknew="1"

Comment: Why did you set Interval? That is executing every 3sec.

Comment: Even if `$checknew` is just a primitive value and not an array it is still a good idea to write `echo json_encode($checknew);`, because then it can be ensured, that it is always properly encode no matter what the content of `$checknew` is and in the code it is clear that the data should be returned as json. If it is `$checknew` is the number `1` then output of `json_encode` will also be `1`. @phpnoob

Comment: because I'm trying to reload the page if the datebase changes, btw I figured out what the problem was (typo), now it stops reloading if the variables match, now I only need to figure out how to pass the value of $old['ertek'] to the var checknew.

Comment: It is as you have passed for checkold. And go for +1 if this answer helped you

Comment: all is working like a charm now, Gary Johnson suggested above that var checkold = "<?php echo $old['ertek'];?>"; would not work, but it does. I'm going to stick to this solution as it is what I needed.